# Spartacus running dev:ssr on multisite not passing requestOrigin from the NgExpressEngineDecorator

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm running a Spartacus SSR Multisite.
This works fine when I'm running `yarn build:ssr` and `yarn serve:ssr`.
The Spartacus NgExpressEngineDecorator nicely passes the original hostname to the application.

But when I run `yarn dev:ssr` for debugging purposes, this fails.
The SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN always returns **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**.
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/core-libs/setup/ssr/engine-decorator/ng-express-engine-decorator.ts#L108

So the baseSite can't be found.

Setting "host" and "publicHost" options on the "serve-ssr" in angular.json doesn't seem to help either. Any ideas how we can solve this issue?

If I have a decent way to debug the multisite SSR, I'd be very happy.

Comment: Workaround at the moment is just to set the BaseSite property in the module config for the site I want to check.

Comment: Didn't check that specific case but an option might be extending your local `/etc/hosts` (if you're on linux/mac) with desired sites (like 127.0.0.1 example.site.local example.site2.local etc) and use that for matching which site you're currently on (of course this might need new `urlPatterns` if you use automatic multisite feature) by accessing your app in the browser/curl using example.site.local

Comment: @MirosławGrochowski That's what fails. We add the hosts to the /etc/hosts, but the dev:ssr server still gives 127.0.0.1 back as SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN

Comment: First of all, it sounds strange that development SSR server behaves differently than the production one. Please double check your environment prod configuration. A few questions: 1. Which version of Spartacus are you using? 2. Where do you serve this application (on local computer or on some other server)? Please note that `yarn dev:ssr` should be used only for development, not production.

Comment: Some side notes, that I believe are not related to your issue, but just ring a bell for me: I) Do you have enabled `server.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');` in your `server.ts`? II) Known issue with SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN in general for versions <3.0.2 https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-coding-guidelines/#workaround-for-known-issue-in-spartacus-302-and-earlier III) And here you have a tutorial how to debug SSR: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/how-to-debug-server-side-rendered-storefront/

Comment: server.set('trust proxy', 'loopback') is what it fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Krzysztof Platis mentioned, putting `server.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');` in `server.ts` is what solved my problem